# Freeze a user - Does Data integration works

Tags: integration, data

Let's assume a salesforce user was integrated with a third party service for integrating the data from other platforms trough OAuth services available in salesforce.

If the respective user got frozen by admin then does it effects the data posting/Integration part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Once user is frozen he/she can not log into system(via UI or API) and so can not make any changes.

here is link for your reference: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_freeze.htm&language=en_US